# How to combine r and python and enviroments in quarto

Tags: python, r, virtualenv, quarto

Quarto can combine r and python (amongst others) in a single document project.
With quarto, you can create virtual environments to isolate your dependencies using either renv, anaconda, env... ([official page](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/virtual-environments.html))

However, I haven't succeeded in combining R, Python and virtual environments in a project (book).
So far, I have tried with creating a renv for R's dependencies and a conda environment for python's. However, when rendering my book, quarto will detect conda environment and tries to run R from there, making it to fail.

Is there a way to fix this?

1. I have a project with an renv folder and env folder, each containing environments for R and python, respectively.
2. I have a simple file such as this one:

```r
# This is a code block with resulting code.
print("This is the output resulting from the code above")
```

3. I run `quarto render`
4. render fails when reaches that simple r code, prompting this error:

```
processing file: conventions.qmd
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/my_folder/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: .main ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
```

5. However, if I run the code by running the code cell from the base environment, it works as expected.

Comment: Based on the error, I would recommend re-installing `stringi`: `renv::install("stringi", rebuild = TRUE)`

Comment: True, that fixed the problem. I was confused because I could run the cell individually from quarto, but reinstalling solved the problem. Thanks